# can't sync my data to database using South

Tags: mysql, django, django-south

> every time I 'python manage.py migrate myapp ' , errors happened , it said that the table is 
>   already exists... Any help ? please...

Comment: -1 read the docs http://pypi.python.org/pypi/South/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use python 'manage.py migrate myapp --fake' for all the migrations before the last one

Comment: do u have more than one migration??